# HTML doesn't read the CSS styling

Tags: html, css

So I'm using XAMPP (if that matters) and every time I restart the local server, the styling stops working.

For example I have this style link right now:

```
<link href="style/mainstyling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Everytime when I restart the local server the styling is actually working, but when I make a change into the css file itself, it doesn't affect the page at all. The fix right now is  when I copy all the css code and put it into another file with completely different name and connect it again with the php (html) page itself.

I've been reading articles about it and I couldn't find any particular answer that could actually be the problem solver in this situations. It's either the cache of the browser or I don't know.

And yes, everything is in the right directory.

Comment: Have you tried hard reload? In chrome shortcut is `ctrl + shift + r`. Long term solution is to turn off cache in XAMPP.

Comment: Turn off cache in XAMPP and see if that helps. Or, if you have some sort of .htaccess-file, check there for cache headings, and also, depending on what server-side language you're using, check to see if there are any settings there that might affect this. Also, you don't need to change the file-name. Just add an url-attribute to the existing one. Like this: `href="style/mainstyling.css#ver.1"` and update the number.

Comment: And hard reload/reload is just `ctrl + F5` or `F5`, as long as you're on Windows.

Comment: You're sure this isn't a simple caching issue? You can disable caching when dev tools is open in the browser, typically.

Comment: I think the hardest refresh fixed the problem for now...

Answer (score 0):

Open up Developer tools in Chrome (F12), go to your network tab and look at the HTTP response of 
mainstyling.css Check that:

1. Got a 200 OK and not a 404.
2. The response Content-Type is "text/css"
3. Check the response body has CSS in it.
4. Run the CSS through a css format checker and check it is valid.